# Java: Undecorated JFrame not displaying Graphics?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jpanel

---

I've been programming in Java for about six months now and have done many work with Graphics in JPanels and JFrames. But recently I got a problem. All the JFrames I've been making before were always `setUndecorated(false)`, but I needed to make one that was `setUndecorated(true)`. So I tried, like usual, just putting the `frame.setUndecorated(true)` above all the `frame`'s specs, so it looked something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setSize(600, 800);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(new custompanel());
}
```

And the `custompanel` class:

```
public class custompanel{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

The `g` in `custompanel` doesn't paint anything.

However, if I remove the `frame.setUndecorated(true)` or change it to `frame.setUndecorated(false)` it will paint a rectangle.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `CustomPanel` extends `JComponent` or `JPanel`, make the frame visible after adding `CustomPanel`. Calling `super.paintComponent(g)` is a good idea to paint any background components.

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but why does that happen? I mean, can't we make it visible before adding the JPanel and after it's visible then add the JPanel?

Comment: @TheSultan The JFrame is a odd beast. Adding new content to the frames content pane doesn't seem to revalidate the container for some reason. You could, alternatively, call revalidate, but calling setVisible is simpler and works across multiple versions of Java

Comment: Swing needs components to be added in this order otherwise the components are not painted. You could call `revalidate` as mentioned by @MadProgrammer but this is typically used when adding components after the frame has been made visible

Comment: @Reimeus But the OP is adding components at runtime ;)